# simple way to assign default value with xmlelement defaultvalue annotation

Tags: java, jaxb, annotations

I have a simple pojo annotated class via JAXB like that :

```
    public class MyPojo
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1234L;
    @XmlElement(name = "Type", required = true, defaultValue = "none")
    @NotNull
    protected SeismicDataAcquisitionSystemType type;
    @XmlElement(name = "IpAddress", required = true)
    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "((1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4]|[0-9]|25[0-5]).){3}(1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])")
    protected String ipAddress;
    @XmlElement(name = "SealServerTcpPort", defaultValue = "1477")
    @NotNull
    protected int sealServerTcpPort;
    @XmlElement(name = "PamServerTcpPort", defaultValue = "1485")
    @NotNull
    protected int pamServerTcpPort;

    /**
     * Obtient la valeur de la propriété type.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link SeismicDataAcquisitionSystemType }
     *     
     */
    public SeismicDataAcquisitionSystemType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * Définit la valeur de la propriété type.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link SeismicDataAcquisitionSystemType }
     *     
     */
    public void setType(SeismicDataAcquisitionSystemType value) {
        this.type = value;
    }

    public boolean isSetType() {
        return (this.type!= null);
    }

    /**
     * Obtient la valeur de la propriété ipAddress.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getIpAddress() {
        return ipAddress;
    }

    /**
     * Définit la valeur de la propriété ipAddress.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setIpAddress(String value) {
        this.ipAddress = value;
    }

    public boolean isSetIpAddress() {
        return (this.ipAddress!= null);
    }

    /**
     * Obtient la valeur de la propriété sealServerTcpPort.
     * 
     */
    public int getSealServerTcpPort() {
        return sealServerTcpPort;
    }

    /**
     * Définit la valeur de la propriété sealServerTcpPort.
     * 
     */
    public void setSealServerTcpPort(int value) {
        this.sealServerTcpPort = value;
    }

    public boolean isSetSealServerTcpPort() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Obtient la valeur de la propriété pamServerTcpPort.
     * 
     */
    public int getPamServerTcpPort() {
        return pamServerTcpPort;
    }

    /**
     * Définit la valeur de la propriété pamServerTcpPort.
     * 
     */
    public void setPamServerTcpPort(int value) {
        this.pamServerTcpPort = value;
    }
}
```

I try to initialize my pojo with default value
like that

```
    MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo();
myPojo.getPamServerTcpPort(); // return 0
setDefaultValues(myPojo); // assign attributes with annotated default values
myPojo.getPamServerTcpPort(); // return 1485
```

I'm trying programmaticaly with the method setDefaultValues(MyPojo loMyPojo) that parse class with java.lang.annotation API and java.lang.reflect API but my code is ugly and doesn't work with my own enumerate default value

I have to mentionned that I cannot modify original class MyPojo because it is itself generated by XSD parsing via JAXB

any idea?

Comment: what framework did you use to generate the class (e.g. Axiom 2)?

Comment: I'm using jaxb api with xjc command un a plugin (krasa)

Answer (score 0):

A quick implementation of your missing function could look like:

```
    public static void setDefaultValues(Object o) throws Exception {
        if (o == null)
            return;
        for (Class<?> clazz = o.getClass(); clazz != Object.class; clazz = clazz.getSuperclass()) {
            for (final Field f : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
                final XmlElement xe = f.getAnnotation(XmlElement.class);
                if (xe != null && xe.defaultValue() != null) {
                    final Class<?> t = f.getType();
                    if (t.isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
                        f.setAccessible(true);
                        f.set(o, xe.defaultValue());
                    } else if (t.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class) || clazz.getSimpleName().equals("int")) {
                        f.setAccessible(true);
                        f.set(o, Integer.parseInt(xe.defaultValue()));
                    } else if (t.isAssignableFrom(Long.class) || clazz.getSimpleName().equals("long")) {
                        f.setAccessible(true);
                        f.set(o, Long.parseLong(xe.defaultValue()));
                    }
                    // else {
                    // TODO: add futher conversions
                    // }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```